# How to get months before a specific date?

Tags: sql

I have a form that I choose a month and get the data.
How would I get the query to get the months before march.

For example If a user enter '3'(march), how do i get the query to get data for 'january/february/march'.
I use sql 2012.

```
SELECT sum(denied) as denied
FROM test
where  year(date)=2016 and month(date)=3 and   denied > 0
```

Comment: Since you know how to get the month name for a given month number, then start from 1 and count down to the given month number and then get the corresponding month names for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's just for 2016 then get the month number from your dropdown, you don't need the variable like i did, i just made it so that it was easier to see.

```
Set @MonthNum = <number> /** e.g. 3 for March **/

SELECT sum(denied) as denied
FROM test
where  year(date)=2016 and month(date) <= @MonthNum and   denied > 0
```